# Implicit function theorem for non $C^1$ mappings

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I know that the inverse function theorem can be proved for differentiable mappings (not $C^1$) by requiring that $Df(x)$ has everywhere maximum rank (here is the reference https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/).

Knowing this I can easily prove the implicit function theorem for differentiable maps such that $D_yf$ (the differential with respect to the last $n$ variables) has maximum rank.

I also know that I can prove the implicit function theorem for mappings that are just continuous on all variables, and $C^1$ only on the variables I'm solving for (I can prove local existence, local uniqueness and continuity of the implicit function), and that this particular result "weakly" extend even by relaxing hypothesis heavily, in the sense that uniqueness of the implicit function may be dropped.
I add a refenrence for those statements https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-4-431-67891-5 .

I was wondering then, as a middle route, if I can prove the implicit function theorem for mappings that are continuous for the first $m-n$ variables, and differentiable for the last $n$ variables, supposing $D_yf$ with everywhere maximum rank, meaning I would like to prove local existence, local uniqueness and continuity of the implicit function.

The thing is, I couldn't find a reference, hence I was wondering if someone either knew a proof, a reference, or a counterexample.

Thanks in advance!